# How do I work with aws rds myql on eclipse(Java)?

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have downloaded aws sdk and connected my account and the database. But now I do not know what I need to do next. How do insert, delete or create table through java on eclipse.

I know to do these in  a local database. I tried changing the url in `getConnection()` function to the my endpoint on eclipse but I keep getting error stating 
"Access denied for user 'aws'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: YES)" (real IP modified for security reasons).

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.Date;

public class MySQLAccess {

  private Connection connect = null;
  private Statement statement = null;
  private PreparedStatement preparedStatement = null;
  private ResultSet resultSet = null;

  private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://aws.cyduxshnlizb.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306";
  final private String user = "myusername";
  final private String passwd = "mypassword";

  public void readDataBase() throws Exception {
    try {
      // This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

      // Setup the connection with the DB
      connect = DriverManager
          .getConnection(url,user,passwd); 

      // Statements allow to issue SQL queries to the database
      statement = connect.createStatement();
      // Result set get the result of the SQL query
      resultSet = statement
          .executeQuery("select * from feedback.comments");
      writeResultSet(resultSet);

      // PreparedStatements can use variables and are more efficient
      preparedStatement = connect
          .prepareStatement("insert into  feedback.comments values (default, ?, ?, ?, ? , ?, ?)");
      // "myuser, webpage, datum, summary, COMMENTS from feedback.comments");
      // Parameters start with 1
      preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
      preparedStatement.setString(2, "TestEmail");
      preparedStatement.setString(3, "TestWebpage");
      preparedStatement.setDate(4, new java.sql.Date(2009, 12, 11));
      preparedStatement.setString(5, "TestSummary");
      preparedStatement.setString(6, "TestComment");
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

      preparedStatement = connect
          .prepareStatement("SELECT myuser, webpage, datum, summary, COMMENTS from feedback.comments");
      resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
      writeResultSet(resultSet);

      // Remove again the insert comment
      preparedStatement = connect
      .prepareStatement("delete from feedback.comments where myuser= ? ; ");
      preparedStatement.setString(1, "Test");
      preparedStatement.executeUpdate();

      resultSet = statement
      .executeQuery("select * from feedback.comments");
      writeMetaData(resultSet);

    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw e;
    } finally {
      close();
    }

  }

  private void writeMetaData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    //   Now get some metadata from the database
    // Result set get the result of the SQL query

    System.out.println("The columns in the table are: ");

    System.out.println("Table: " + resultSet.getMetaData().getTableName(1));
    for  (int i = 1; i<= resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++){
      System.out.println("Column " +i  + " "+ resultSet.getMetaData().getColumnName(i));
    }
  }

  private void writeResultSet(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {
    // ResultSet is initially before the first data set
    while (resultSet.next()) {
      // It is possible to get the columns via name
      // also possible to get the columns via the column number
      // which starts at 1
      // e.g. resultSet.getSTring(2);
      String user = resultSet.getString("myuser");
      String website = resultSet.getString("webpage");
      String summary = resultSet.getString("summary");
      Date date = resultSet.getDate("datum");
      String comment = resultSet.getString("comments");
      System.out.println("User: " + user);
      System.out.println("Website: " + website);
      System.out.println("Summary: " + summary);
      System.out.println("Date: " + date);
      System.out.println("Comment: " + comment);
    }
  }

  // You need to close the resultSet
  private void close() {
    try {
      if (resultSet != null) {
        resultSet.close();
      }

      if (statement != null) {
        statement.close();
      }

      if (connect != null) {
        connect.close();
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You should review your AWS RDS security group  to see if you can accesss from your IP

Comment: I am able to access the database and create table using mysql workbench